# Force password on reading svn repository

Tags: apache, svn, git-svn, subversion-edge

I was trying to make my repository not visible for the anonymous users(not even the read access).

I have done some changes to accomplish this but all these are not working for me.

Please see the changes below:

```
My File: /var/www/svnRepos/KH/conf/svnserve.conf

anon-access = none
auth-access = write
password-db = passwd
```

I have also put these in my subversion-KH.conf file

```
<LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
   Require valid-user
</LimitExcept>
```

I have these in my acl(svn-acl-conf-KH) file

```
[groups]
support_rw = Rsingh, Ddeep, Akumar
[/]
@support_rw = rw
* =
```

But when i am trying open the Repository it is giving me error on Tortoise as 
"Server sent unexpected return value (403 forbidden) in response to OPTIONS"

And i am getting the error in Apache logs like this
"Access denied: - OPTIONS KH:/"

And when i change my file acl(svn-acl-conf-KH) file to this

```
[groups]
support_rw = Rsingh, Ddeep, Akumar
[/]
@support_rw = rw
* = r
```

Then it is opening the repository(but then anyone can open & read my repository).

Can anyone tell me where i am getting the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find out how to accomplish this.

If we have to make the anonymous reader to read the repository. We have to put the LimitExcept tag in the subversion(repository-conf-file).conf file.

Here in above question we have to make sure that anonymous reader is not even able to read the repository so just delete the LimitExcept tag in the subversion.conf file.

It solved my problem and it is running perfectly fine for me.